# Why the While loop keep running in the following Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am new to Python, and could not figure out why the While loop is kept running in the following code?

```
prompt = "Please enter the customer's age: "
age = input(prompt)
while age != 'quit':
    age = int(age)
    if age <= 3:
        print("Welcome little buddy, no charges for you!")
    elif age > 3 and age < 12:
        print("The ticket price is $10")
    elif age >= 12:
        print("The ticket price is 15")
    elif age == 'quit':
        print("rerun the code")
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to stop?

Comment: age does not get modified inside the loop.  Furthermore, if you type 'quit' then an exception will be thrown when you try to interpret it as an int.  Put the input prompt inside your loop, and don't use integers.

Comment: If you never reassign `age` within the loop, the loop will always be testing the same value against the condition.

Comment: Because once you enter the while loop you are not exiting it

Comment: @Turksarama Thanks for your response. If I put input prompt inside the while loop, then how I will define age before the While loop? I mean the data type of age.

Comment: Python has dynamic typing, so you don't need to define the datatype anywhere.  As long as it isn't `'quit'` then it will work.  `None` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you expect this from your code..i did some changes.your while loop didn't stop because it didn't have a reason to stop.it is testing same value again and again against condition

```
def agetest():
age = input("Please enter the customer's age: ")
age = int(age)
if 0<age <= 3:
    print("Welcome little buddy, no charges for you!")
    agetest()
elif age > 3 and age < 12:
    print("The ticket price is $10")
    agetest()
elif age >= 12:
    print("The ticket price is 15")
    agetest()
elif age == -1:
    print("thnks")
```

agetest()

here is the answer with while loop

```
age=0
while(age!= -1):

print("Please enter the customer's age: ")
age = int(input())
if 0<age <= 3:
    print("Welcome little buddy, no charges for you!")

elif age > 3 and age < 12:
    print("The ticket price is $10")

elif age >= 12:
    print("The ticket price is 15")

elif age == -1:
    print("thanks")
```

Comment: @ Pasindu Senarath Thanks for your response. I am trying to write it using While loop. Can you please fix this code using While loop instead of using def?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and did some modifications.
problems were :

1. you were getting input out the loop so it was not interactive.
2. there was no statement to modify age to break the loop.
3. you can not cast the input as integer if you are expecting a string input.

   > ```
   >  while True:
   >         prompt = "Please enter the customer's age: "
   >         age = input(prompt)
   >         if age == 'quit':
   >           print("rerun the code")
   >           break
   >         elif age <= 3:
   >             print("Welcome little buddy, no charges for you!")
   >         elif age > 3 and age < 12:
   >             print("The ticket price is $10")
   >         elif age >= 12:
   >             print("The ticket price is 15")
   > ```

Comment: @@ Sach your code gives the following error when run for any integer.